# Google App Maker: external javascript library

Tags: google-app-maker

I'm creating a POC using google app maker. I plan on using a JS library that has a dependency on Jquery. I've listed JQuery as an "external resource" to start with and added an H1 element on my html with the following code as part of a client script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("h1").click(function(){
      console.log("jquery works");
   });
});
```

When I preview my app and click on the element, nothing is logged. When I inspect the elements, I can see both the Jquery library and the code above, but the event is not triggering when I click on the element. Any suggestions? The ultimate goal is to be able to use https://querybuilder.js.org/ within the app I'm creating.

Comment: Did you use the widget builder and added a 'Label' widget that you designated as an 'H1' type label or did you add an H1 type element using a document appendElement?

Comment: @MarkusMalessa I dragged and dropped an html box from the widgets and then added the content: <h1>test</h1> on the properties listed on the right. I can see it renders accurately when I preview the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My best guess is that when you say that you added the code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("h1").click(function(){
      console.log("jquery works");
   });
});
```

to the client script, what you did was created a client script under the **SCRIPTS** section of App Maker and then added the code there. If that is so, that is why it's not working.

What you need to do is to use client scripting in the widget event handlers. Each widget has event handlers and the **HTML** widget is not an exception. What I recommend is to add the code to the **onAttach** event handler of the **HTML** widget:

[image]}

Also, you can get rid of the `document.ready` part and just use the code you see in the image above. That should do the trick.

**BONUS:** If you will be using *classes* and *ids*, for it to work you will need to use the **allowUnsafeHtml** option:

[image]

I hope this helps for now. If you need something else, I'll be happy to help you.

Comment: Just wondering, is this because of the order that App Maker loads external libraries compared to the scripts? I tried the same using the h1 click handler in the app start up client script and it also did not work, but as you suggested if you put the jquery click event in the widget onAttach event then it will work.

Comment: @MarkusMalessa Not really. Actually, all the code that you put in the client scripts, it needs to be invoked using a widget event handler. For example a button, it will be the `onClick` event handler; A dropdown, perhaps the `onValueChange` event handler, etc. You get the idea.

Comment: I find that somewhat interesting, given that App Maker runs off of Google Apps Script. In GAS I am able to leave my  onClick in the HTML absent and as long as I load my <script> files first and just include jquery in my scripts and it works just fine. This way in GAS I am able to put all my handlers in a separate script file rather than having to include an onClick in all my html and then calling the function from my script files.

Comment: Thank you @Morfinismo, that did the job. I'm thinking the widget is added to the DOM dynamically after the DOM is ready and that's why the event is not attached to the widget.

Comment: @jorgeAChacon I believe you are right based on what the documentation says... read this https://developers.google.com/appmaker/ui/widgets#creation